Could contrails be used to de-energize hurricanes?
I have had this theory bouncing around in my head since 9/11 and I would like someone's feedback.
It was a published fact that grounding air traffic in the United States in the days following the 9/11 attacks made a significant measurable impact on North American continental temperatures.  I believe average temperatures rose by over 1 degree Celsius due to the lack of the the artificial "clouds".
What would happen if a country sent a small fleet of aircraft to deliberately create contrails to shield the oceanic waters from sun light leading up to the approach of a hurricane?  I have read that every degree of ocean temperature can make a 10-20 mph difference in hurricane airspeed.  It is also published that cloud cover during the day blocks solar radiation, but cloud cover at night creates a blanketing effect to retain solar heat.  Such a plan would have to retain the contrails during daylight hours and allow them to dissipate during the evening to allow heat to otherwise escape back into the atmosphere.
Couldn't this be a low-cost approach to de-energize a hurricane or also even potentially create a steering effect away from more populated areas?
These comments are not related to the terraforming plans that others have come up with more recently to combat climate change by blocking the sun.  I think about this every time I hear news reports that a storm is expected to strengthen as it hits the warm open waters of the Gulf Of Mexico.

what does your research show,do you have any links to more information about this?

What you refer to is called "geoengineering" and more specifically "climate engineering", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_engineering . There is a lot of research on how to put stuff into the atmosphere that reflects sunlight.
